# Problems with init=bin/sh working

Tags: ssh, pi-3b+, password, init

I followed the below instructions. Putting the init at the end of the sole line in cmdline.

```
boot=UUID=2311-4211 disk=UUID=69a6af94-e21a-450d-bf5e-fcc08d992566 init=/bin/sh
```

I return sd card to pi and it boots up like normal. What am I doing wrong?

- Power down and pull the SD card out from your Pi and put it into your computer.
- Open the file `cmdline.txt` and add `init=/bin/sh` to the end. This will cause the machine to boot to single-user mode.
- Put the SD card back in the Pi and boot.
- When the prompt comes up, type `su` to log in as root (no password needed).
- Type `passwd pi` and then follow the prompts to enter a new password.
- Shut the machine down, then pull the card again and put the `cmdline.txt` file back the way it was by removing the `init=/bin/sh` bit.

Comment: so your whole cmdline.txt is `boot=UUID=2311-4211 disk=UUID=69a6af94-e21a-450d-bf5e-fcc08d992566` (with perhaps different ID's)? because mine looks like `root=PARTUUID=b16b00b5-02 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait` ... is yours a NOOBS image?

Comment: Where exactly is `cmdline.txt` stored that you modified? Do you mounted the first partition of the SD card? Please address me with @Ingo, otherwise I won't see your reply.